# Enabling recursive subfolder search when opening files in applications on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, search

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Sublime Text on a Lenovo T530 for php development.

I was previously using Ubuntu 18.04 with Sublime to work on our codebase which has several sub-directories.  My usual method of opening a file was to use the search bar, which would recursively search through all the subfolders in a convenient manner.

This does not work with 20.04, the Nautilus(?) window I am presented with only searches in the current folder, without recursively searching subfolders.  Suddenly finding files is quite time consuming!

This issue is not specific to Sublime Text, upon checking other apps I find it to be a universal problem in Ubuntu 20.04.  If I open a Nautilus file manager window search behaves as expected but when using the `File` menu `Open File` in an application it does not.

I've looked through all settings I can find including clicking `All Locations` of `Search in subfolders` in the Nautilus settings.

I've also checked forums and found similar questions from previous Ubuntu versions but the suggestions given have not worked.